# Capturing username from grunt shell command

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I am trying to create a Grunt task that will run a 'finger -lp' command to capture both the name and login of the user who's logged into the computer.

Here's the standard output of 'finger -lp' when executed from a terminal:

```
    Login: abc123                     Name: John Doe
    Directory: /Users/abc123          Shell: /bin/bash
    On since Thu Oct 30 19:40 (EDT) on console, idle 19:34 (messages off)
    On since Fri Oct 31 10:24 (EDT) on ttys002
    No Mail.
```

Here is how I am running the same command using grunt.util.spawn:

```
    module.exports = function (grunt) {
      grunt.registerTask('username', '',
       function () {
         var done = this.async();
         grunt.util.spawn({
          cmd: 'finger',
          args: ['-lp'],
            opts: {stdio: 'inherit'},
           fallback: ''
        }, function (err, result, code) {
           console.info('RESULT: ',err, result, code);
           done();
         });
       });
     };
```

Here is the output from the console.info statement above:

```
    abc123@uschamngn0qfft3:~/WorkFiles/john-doe/$ grunt username

    Running "username" task
    Login: abc123                   Name: John Doe
    Directory: /Users/abc123        Shell: /bin/bash
    On since Thu Oct 30 19:40 (EDT) on console, idle 19:34 (messages off)
    On since Fri Oct 31 10:24 (EDT) on ttys002
    No Mail.
    RESULT: null { stdout: '', stderr: '', code: 0, toString: [Function] } 0
```

So, the Grunt task isn't executing the command `finger -lp` in a way that is outputting the result to the terminal, but isn't being captured by the `grunt.util.spawn` process.  The `stdout` in the `result` object is empty.

```
    RESULT: null { stdout: '', stderr: '', code: 0, toString: [Function] } 0
```

I'm following the examples from the [node](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) because it's what [grunt.util.spawn](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.util#grunt.util.spawn) uses.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  The way to capture the login and username of the user in a grunt command is to run a spawn process using the `finger -lp` command.  Then I run a regex on the output.

This works on a Mac:

```
     grunt.registerTask('username', '',
      function () {
        var done = this.async();
        grunt.util.spawn({
          cmd: 'finger',
          args: ['-lp']
        }, function (err, result, code) {
          var username = '';
          var output = result.stdout;
          if (output) {
             var matches = result.stdout.match(/Login: ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[\s\t]+Name: ([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)/);
             var login = matches[1];
             var name = matches[2];
             var username = (name + ' ' + login).toUpperCase();
          }
          grunt.config('developerName', username);
          done();
        });
      });
```

This task runs before all other tasks in my Grunt process and I save the output of the `username` task to a value called `developerName` in `grunt.config` where I can then use it during any other process that follows, like this:

```
    module.exports = {

      dist: {
        options: {
          cssDir: "public/resources/",
          sassDir: "src/resources/",
          quiet: true,
          environment: "production",
          outputStyle: "compressed",
          force: true,
          banner: "/*! Concatenated on <%= grunt.template.today('mm-dd-yyyy') %> at <%= grunt.template.today('h:MM:ss TT') %> by <%= grunt.config('developerName') %> */\n"
        }
      }

    }
```